# how to separate a string char by char and add a symbol after in c#

Tags: string, visual-studio, c#-4.0

Any idea how i can separate a string with character and numbers, for example 
 12345ABC678 to make it look like this
 1|2|3|4|5|A|B|C|6|7|8??
Or if this is not possile, how can i take this string a put every character or nr of it in a different textBox like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
  String aString = "AaBbCcDd";
  var chars = aString.ToCharArray();
```

Then you can loop over the array (chars)

Comment: Gives me this error 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToCharArray' and no extension method 'ToCharArray' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.Join` and `String.ToCharArray`:

```
string input = "12345ABC678";
string result = String.Join("|", input.ToCharArray());
```

Instead of `ToCharArray`(creates a new array) you could also cast the `string` to `IEnumerable<char>` to force it to use [the right overload of `String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string result = String.Join("|", (IEnumerable<char>)input);
```

Comment: Link to docs: [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7#System_String_Join__1_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) and [String.ToCharArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netframework-4.7#System_String_ToCharArray).